# Producer-consumer processing pattern for Kafka processing

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm implementing a streaming pipeline that resembles the illustration below:

```
*K-topic1* ---> processor1 ---> *K-topic2* ---> processor2 --> 
*K-topic3* ---> processor3 --> *K-topic4*
```

The K-topic components represent Kafka topics and the processor components  code (Python/Java).

For the processor component, the intention is to read/consume data from the topic, perform some processing/ETL on it, and persist the results to the next topic in the chain as well as persistent store such as S3.

I have a question regarding the design approach.

The way I see it, each processor component should encapsulate both consumer and producer functionality.

Would the best approach be to have a Processor module/class that could contain KafkaConsumer and KafkaProducer classes ? To date, most examples I've seen have separate consumer and producer components which are run separately and would entail running double the number of components
as opposed to encapsulating producers & consumers within each Processor object.

Any suggestions/references are welcome.

This question is different from

[Designing a component both producer and consumer in Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823592/designing-a-component-both-producer-and-consumer-in-kafka)

as that question specifically mentions using Samza which is not the case here.

Comment: I will suggest you to explore the kafka streams api as your requirement is correct fit for it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Designing a component both producer and consumer in Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823592/designing-a-component-both-producer-and-consumer-in-kafka)

Comment: Not really - that question specifically refers to Samza.

Answer (score 1):

> the intention is to read/consume data from the topic, perform some processing/ETL on it, and persist the results to the next topic in the chain

This is exactly the strength of Kafka Streams and/or KSQL. You could use the `Processor` API, but from what you describe, I think you'll only need the Streams DSL API

> persist the results to the next topic in the chain as well as persistent store such as S3.

From the above topic, you can use a Kafka Connect Sink for getting the topic data into these other external systems. There is no need to write a consumer to do this for you.